# Returning a 2d array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, segmentation-fault

I am trying to return a 2d array from a function but for some reason when I call the function in my main it causes a segmentation fault.

```
char **upper_case_word(char **word,int size){
        int i =0;
        int i2=0;
        // this gets the number of words
        int length = upper_counter(word,size);
        //this gets the size of the largest word
        int size2 = length_upper(word,size);

        char ** upper =malloc(length*sizeof(char*));

        for(i =0; i <length; i++){
                upper[i]= malloc(size2*sizeof(char*));
        }
        i =0;

        for(i =0; i<=size2; i++){

                for(i2 =0; i2<(sizeof(word[i])/sizeof(word[i][0])); i2++){   
                             if(isupper(word[i][i2])!=0){     
                                upper[i]=word[i];
                        }
                }
        }
        return upper;
}
int main(){
   //this is causing the segmentation fault.
   char ** upper = upper_case_word(words,size);

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: `upper[i]= malloc(size2*sizeof(char*));` --> `upper[i]= malloc(size2*sizeof(char));` or simply `upper[i]= malloc(size2);`

Comment: What's `words` and `size` in `main`?

Comment: There's more wrong with your code, than just that segfault. For starters: What do you think is the result of `sizeof(word[i])`? It's probably not what you think it is. Also to copy a string you have to `strdup` or `memcpy` it. Simple assignment `upper[i] = word[i]` doesn't work.

Comment: words is a different 2d array and size is the size of the 2d array

Comment: Detail: `char **upper_case_word(char **word,int size)` does not return a 2D array.  It returns a pointer.  Thinking `char**` is an array is like the mis-code of `sizeof(word[i])/sizeof(word[i][0]`.  `words` is not an array either.

Comment: To add to what @chux posted, you're returning a pointer to an array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Can you explain what your are trying to achieve with this code? The code contains many bugs (see my answer) but it's hard to help you fixing it as it is a bit unclear what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this covers all problems but here a few to start with:

What you allocate is not a 2D array. Instead you allocate an array of pointers and for each of these pointer, you allocate an array. That last array should be an array of char. However, your code is:

```
upper[i]= malloc(size2*sizeof(char*));
                              ^^^^^
                              Should be char, not char*
```

But that is not the cause of the seg fault - it's just allocating more memory than needed.

The outer array, i.e. `upper` is allocated using `length` like:

```
char ** upper =malloc(length*sizeof(char*));
                      ^^^^^^
```

but later you iterate it using `size2` - here:

```
    for(i =0; i<=size2; i++){
```

So in case `size2` is greater than or equal to `length`, you access out of bounds. That may cause a seg fault.

Then this part:

```
sizeof(word[i])/sizeof(word[i][0])
```

Are you sure that is doing what you want?

It is the same as:

```
sizeof(char*)/sizeof(char)
```

or just

```
sizeof(char*)
```

I doubt that is what you want.

Then you have this code:

```
                    if(isupper(word[i][i2])!=0){     
                        upper[i]=word[i];
                    }
```

Here you change the pointer value held by `upper[i]`. That makes no sense and it's a memory leak because you overwrite a pointer that points to dynamic allocated memory with another pointer.